# In react JS fields losing focus after first onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form But When I am start typing focus goes out first time in react.

In my component below, the input field loses focus after typing a character. While using Chrome's Inspector, it looks like the whole form is being re-rendered instead of just the value attribute of the input field when typing.

Please see below code:

```
<Field
        name='description'
       // onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        //value={this.state.description}
        component={props => {
          return (
            <MentionTextArea  {...props} userTags={userTags} tags={postTags}/> 
          )
        }}
```

MentionTextArea Component:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
import { MentionsInput, Mention } from 'react-mentions'
import defaultStyle from './defaultStyle'

class MentionTextArea extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(prop)
    }
    handleOnChange (e) {
        this.props.input.onChange(e.target.value); 
    }
    render() {
       // const { input, meta, ...rest } = this.props;
        return (
            <MentionsInput 
                value={this.props.input.value || ''}
                onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}
                singleLine={false}
                style={ defaultStyle }
                markup="@[__display__](__type__:__id__)"
                >
                   <Mention trigger="@"
                        data={this.props.userTags}
                        type="userTags"
                        style={{ backgroundColor: '#d1c4e9' }}
                        renderSuggestion={ (suggestion, search, highlightedDisplay) => (
                            <div className="user">
                                { highlightedDisplay }
                            </div>
                        )}
                    />
                    <Mention trigger="#"
                        data={this.props.tags}
                        type="tags"
                        style={{ backgroundColor: '#d1c4e9' }}
                        renderSuggestion={ (suggestion, search, highlightedDisplay) => (
                            <div className="user">
                                { highlightedDisplay }
                            </div>
                        )}
                    />
            </MentionsInput>
        );
    }
}

export default MentionTextArea
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you show how are you rendering the form

Comment: <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit.bind(this)}> 
<Field
        name='description'
       // onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
        //value={this.state.description}
        component={props => {
          return (
            <MentionTextArea  {...props} userTags={userTags} tags={postTags}/> 
          )
        }}
</form>
let connection = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)

var reduxConnectedComponent = connection(CreatePostForm)

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'CreatePost' // a unique identifier for this form
})(reduxConnectedComponent)

Comment: are you giving a key somewhere which is uniquely generated. Also try `let connection = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) var reduxConnectedComponent = reduxForm({ form: 'CreatePost' // a unique identifier for this form }) export default connection(reduxConnectedComponent)`

Comment: I am new in reactJS can you please provide me link or guide where we need to add key ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's common problem for people new to redux-form please check this [issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1094) you'll find an answer there.

You must define the stateless function outside of your render() method, or else it will be recreated on every render and will force the Field to rerender because its component prop will be different. Example from official [redux-form documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/field.md/#2-a-stateless-function):

```
// outside your render() method
const renderField = (field) => (
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...field.input} type="text"/>
      {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && 
       <span className="error">{field.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
  )

// inside your render() method
<Field name="myField" component={renderField}/>
```

Comment: What is not working, you use arrow function to create MentionTextArea. You can't do this. This is constructing a new component function on every render. So it's normal behavior that your input loses focus. Look at [example](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/field.md/#2-a-stateless-function) in documentation and rewrite your code.

Comment: Hi ! You should summarize the content of the linked page with the relevant informations for the current question. It will be better for later reader in case the link dies.

Comment: Ok, I will do it.