# Ant Design Input loses focus on input change

Tags: reactjs, antd, higher-order-functions

I have a form that is wrapped by a `Security` component to make sure that users without specific permissions cannot see it. The problem is that I keep losing the focus on that input field on each keystroke.

```
       <Security
            component={() => (
                <FormItem
                  label='Name
                  form={form}
                  name="name"
                  rules={[RequiredRule]}
                >
                  <Input />
              </FormItem>    
            )}
          />
```

```
export const Security = ({ component: Component, history, permissions, ...props }) => {
  // if user has permissions returns the component otherwise returns null 
};
```

I skipped quite a few lines of code for brevity but the point is that I pass my `Form.Item` into the `Security` component and depending on conditions I either get null or the component I passed.

The problem with the focus does not persist if I comment out that `Security` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I was not supposed to declare the `Form.Item` as an arrow function inside the `component` attribute but put it in the variable outside of my `render` method.

```
formToRender = () => {
  return (
              <FormItem
                  label='Name'
                  form={form}
                  name="name"
                  rules={[RequiredRule]}
                >
                  <Input />
              </FormItem> 
       )
}
```

```
          <Security
            component={formToRender}
          />
```

I found the solution thanks to that gentleman https://stackoverflow.com/a/46172927/13288420